# How to make a post request to log in https://analytics.oag.com/analyser-client/home (Javascript website)

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, reactjs, curl, web-crawler

I have tried to curl using command

```
curl 'https://analytics.oag.com/analyser-client/home' -H 'Accept-Language: 
en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Accept-Language: en- 
US,en;q=0.9' -H 'Host: analytics.oag.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 
(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF- 
8' --data '{"username":"test","password":"test"}'
```

But it doesn't seem to work... Not sure what parts am I missing.. Any idea on how to log in this website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Not sure what parts am I missing` - you're missing a cookie session id, and referer header, and the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header, and your Content-Type header is wrong (it's supposed to be `Content-Type: application/json`), also the login page is loading itself twice if you visit it without a cookie session (first it obtains a cookie session, then it refreshes itself), you should probably follow suite to login. you specifically mentioned python, i don't know how to do it in python, but here's how i would do it in PHP, with [hhb_curl](https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php):

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
require_once ('hhb_.inc.php');
$hc = new hhb_curl ( '', true );
// getting cookie session and refresh (dunno why we need to refresh, but the login page javascript is doing it, so follow suite)
$hc->exec ( 'https://analytics.oag.com/analyser-client/home' )->exec ( 'https://analytics.oag.com/analyser-client/home' );
$response = $hc->setopt_array ( array (
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://analytics.oag.com/analyser-client/broker-services/login/validate',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Origin: https://analytics.oag.com', // i don't think curl set this header this automatically
                'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' 
        ),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode ( array (
                'username' => 'username?',
                'password' => 'password?' 
        ) ) 
) )->exec ()->getResponseBody ();
var_dump ( $response );
$parsed = @json_decode ( $response, true );
if (empty ( $parsed ) || $parsed ['status'] === 'ERROR') {
    throw new \RuntimeException ( 'failed to login! ' . $response );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really works! But I am just wondering how could I navigate to other websites while I stay logged in? I am really not familiar with php, so is there any helpful tutorial on this?

Comment: @TiantianTian just keep using the same curl handle (or in this case, hhb_curl handle), it will keep using your session id cookie, which will keep you logged in. for example, to get the front page after logging in, do `$html=$hc->exec('https://analytics.oag.com/analyser-client/home')->getStdOut(); var_dump($html);` . and sorry, i don't know of any tutorial for this stuff. i learned it through trial and error whilst trying to log in to other websites, pretty much.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! Just one more thing, how do you know the url for CURLOPT_URL? If we want to log in other websites, how do we know what to include in 'CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER =>'? Did you just figure that out through the network section in chrome developer tool? Thanks again for your help!! Really appreciate it!!!

Comment: @TiantianTian `Did you just figure that out through the network section in chrome developer tool?` - yes i did! :) for most websites, chrome dev tools is sufficient. but for a select few, `Fiddler Proxy` may be (not strictly) needed. (not strictly needed, but can make it a lot easier to figure out)

Comment: Thanks again for your help! One last question, how could I make a post request on another page after getting logged in? It's like logging in another page after logging in. I tried to follow the same steps by using $response = $hc->setopt_array(...), but it seems that I have to log in again in this way... How could I work around with it? Again I really appreciate your help!!!!

Comment: Also the cookies are set by javascript, is there any way hhb_curl could detect these cookies? Thanks any way in advance!!

Comment: @TiantianTian it can't directly take cookies from javascript, but you can manually extract the cookies from the javascript and give them to hhb_curl via CURLOPT_COOKIELIST. although, i doubt i can be of more help without access to an actual valid account/password combination.